# Android Studio Deploying to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, backend

I couldn't deploy my webapp with Android Studio. It gives error `com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist`
How to solve this problem ? (In eclipse I was able to deploy it easily)

In backend:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;
```

Backend `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
}
```

App's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')

}
```

And the error message:

```
error: package com.google.android.gcm.server does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line to your backend's `build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
```